# label x-axis by another column and label string at plot based on condition

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get graphy of geom_point in ggplot. x-axis is  `City` and y is  `popu`

I have this data frame like :

```
d <- data.frame(City = LETTERS[1:9],
           popu = c(8975,3421,5433,1066,4529,9012,6732,5801,3396),
           Country = c("UA","UA","AS","UK","UA","AS","UK","Is","Is"))
```

My current code looks like this:

```
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(City, popu)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Country))
```

Which gives me :
[image]

I would like to get plot with  x-axis is  `City` and y is  `popu`,

but x-axis label not by City and color by `Country` ,
kind of like this,same Country will get same color and nearby:
[image]

also label City if pop > 7500, for example like :
[image]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my best guess as to what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Country, y = popu)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(color = Country),
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.5, seed = 1)
  ) +
  geom_text( # label cities over 7500 population
    aes(label = ifelse(popu > 7500, paste("City", City), "")),
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.5, seed = 1),
    vjust = 1.2
  )
```

Using `position = position_jitter` will keep the points from overlapping, and setting the seed will make sure the text labels get jittered the same way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I want using group by County then plot every citys ,is possible?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your new picture is much clearer. I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry I'm not clarify my question. Your code is awesome! Thank you so much!